# How can I create a Set of delegate protocol items in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Let's assume I have five `UIView` objects which all conform to a particular protocol. I have an object which should maintain a list of these objects, and message them all when necessary.

```
protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject {
    func doSomething()
}
```

The problem is, when I go to add these `UIView`s to a Set variable, the compiler produces an error because `MyProtocol` does not conform to `Hashable`. I can understand the reasoning for this, can anyone think of good ways to overcome this? In the meantime I considered using NSHashTable instead, but you lose the nice enumeration features of Sets.

---

Updating answer to post some sample code (this is still not working)

```
protocol MyProtocol: class, AnyObject {
    func doSomething()
}

class MyClass {
    var observers: Set<MyProtocol> = Set<MyProtocol>()
}
```

Comment: What have you done that it says you should implement Hashable ? The code that you have listed is fine. It has no constraint to Hash.

Answer (score 0):

As you are defining protocol for class so you need to write 'class' keyword before inheriting any other protocol:

```
    protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject, Hashable{
         func doSomething()
    }


    class MyClass<T: MyProtocol> {

         var observers: Set<T> = Set<T>()
    }
```

Change your protocol to this and it will work fine.
You can refer [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for that, however the compiler still insists that the `Hashable` protocol isn't implemented.

Comment: Can I see your complete file? or you can send me a demo project?

Comment: AnyObject itself is a protocol which is marked as @objc. Do we still need the class ?

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne No, It will work fine without any error. As I am seeing that I can run the project with or without the class error free

Comment: @Ricky Can you please say that where are you defining that Protocol?

Comment: Sorry guys, didn't realise I was working in Swift 2. I just tried with Swift 1 and it seems like this problem is nonexistent.

Comment: Sorry again. Spoke to soon. (Xcode Playgrounds are useless). I get the same error in Swift 1 and 2, even with the class keyword. I've just updated my question with some more code.

Comment: @Ricky Is it necessary to create Set or what you like to achieve?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon As I said, there are alternatives, but I'm curious :)

Comment: @Ricky I'm too! You can check my edited answer, it's working my end. Check your's

Comment: @SohilR.Memon Interesting, this will make the compiler happy, but doesn't hold for when you want to instantiate your class and add items to the Set.